# Not getting Calories from google fit sensor API. What all data types does sensor API supports?

Tags: android, android-sensors, google-fit, google-fit-api

I am not Getting calories from Sensor API. However, sensor API is returning data for Location Sample and Steps count.

Also, is there any way of getting live data of session which is still going on?

Here is my code

```
                    dataSourceRequest = new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
                            .setDataTypes( DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE)
                            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE)
                            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED)
                            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)

                            .build();


                    Fitness.getSensorsClient(MainActivity.this, account).findDataSources(dataSourceRequest).addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<List<DataSource>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(List<DataSource> dataSources) {


                            for (DataSource dataSource : dataSources) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                                Log.e(TAG, "Data Source type: " + dataSource.getDataType().getName());

                                if(dataSource.getDataType() == DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE) {

                                    Log.e(TAG, "Data source for LOCATION_SAMPLE found! Registering.");
                                    registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_LOCATION_SAMPLE);
                                }

                                if(dataSource.getDataType() == DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE) {

                                    Log.e(TAG, "Data source for STEP_SAMPLE found! Registering.");
                                    registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_CUMULATIVE);
                                }

                                if(dataSource.getDataType() == DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED) {

                                    Log.e(TAG, "Data source for CALORIE_SAMPLE found! Registering.");
                                    registerFitnessDataListener(dataSource, DataType.TYPE_CALORIES_EXPENDED);
                                }
                            }

                            Log.e(TAG, "Sensor API Enabled " + dataSources.size());
                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(MainActivity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                            Log.e(TAG, "Exception- "+e);
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: Have you got any solution?

Comment: i have used google fit api to start activity and then fetch the results.